# Is there a way to use postgresql function to calculate weighted average in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

To calculate weighted average by a company's market capacity, I have a method like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.weighted_average(column)
    market_cap_sum = sum(:market_cap)
    array = []
    find_each do |company|
      next if company.send(column).nil?
      next if company.market_cap.nil?
      array << (company.market_cap.to_d/market_cap_sum) * company.send(column)
    end
    array.sum
  end
end
```

This code works fine but it's just slow to calculate. If there is a way to calculate by postgresql function, I wanna use it.

To calculate standard deviation there is a function like this, but I couldn't find how to calculate standard deviation with weighted average.

```
Company.select('stddev_pop(price) as stddev')
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Using YourModel.select('stddev_pop(column_name) as stddev') does not work?

Comment: Can you provide an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with a basic schema?

Answer (score 9):

The math in this method does not seem to be well known.  Enjoy this old programmer's trick.

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    w real,   /* Weight. May be an integer count or other weight. */
    v real);  /* Value. The value v is to be weighted by w. */
```

Populate the table with one copy of value "1" and ten copies of value "10":

```
insert into data values(1, 1);
insert into data values(10, 2);
```

Then run the following query to obtain weighted statistical values:

```
SELECT
  min(v),
  sum(w*v)/sum(w) AS wavg,
  max(v),
  sqrt((sum(w*v^2)-(sum(w*v)^2)/sum(w))/(sum(w)-1)) AS wstdev
    FROM data;
```

Result is:

```
 min |  wavg   | max |      wstdev       
-----+---------+-----+-------------------
   1 | 1.90909 |   2 | 0.301511344577763
(1 row)
```

Comment: `Populate the table with one copy of value "1" and ten copies of value "10"...` Are you sure? Seems, you have put ten copies of value 2.

Comment: I just want to point out that `sum(w) - 1` on the denominator is an approximation. It works when the sum of the weights equal the number of observations. If one wants to be precise, the denominator should be `(N - 1) * N * sum(w)` where `N` is the number of observations. See [definition of weighted stdv](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch2/weightsd.pdf)